# Optimize file and number line count in Python

Tags: python, optimization, profiling

I got a python project with many folders, files (.css, .py, .yml, etc.) and lines of code. For this project, I made a tool called "statistics" that gives me informations about the entire project such as :

> Global statistics:
>
> Entire project ::                              32329 lines
>   Project main files (.py, .yml) ::              8420 lines
>   Project without vendor part ::                  1070 lines
>   Core (src directory) ::                          394 lines
>   Core compared to project main files ::           5 %         Kraken
>   Framework (vendor/*.py) ::               7350 lines
>   Main files Python code ::                       93 %
>   Vendor Python code ::                           87 %
>   Entire project size ::                          37M

To get all these numbers, I mainly use two functions:

```
def count_folder_lines(self, path):
    files = glob.glob(path, recursive=True)
    number = 0
    for file in files:
        num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(file))
        number += num_lines
    return number
```

and

```
def count_number_of_files(self, path):
    files = glob.glob(path, recursive=True)
    return len(files)
```

The first one is used to count the number of lines in a folder and the second one is used to count the number of specific files (ex: src/*.py).
But to get the project's statistics, it takes between 4.9 and 5.3 seconds, which is a lot.

Is there any way to make it faster ? Does parallel programming or using Cython would change something ?

Have a nice day,
Thank you.

Comment: looking at file size would be much faster than counting the number of lines

Comment: In my case, I really need the number of lines

Comment: The problem is that you are always bounded by your longest file.  I tried it by me and for a file of 20,000 lines, it can take a few seconds.  Lines of code is a number that doesn't change often.  My suggestion, therefore: either run a script to calculate the result parallel to compilation (if that's when you're reading it out) or run a background task to calculate it every x minutes or hours.  In both cases, output the result to a file and then simply read it whenever you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the most efficient solution for me :
I'm using multiprocessing module to count the number of lines of each file in parallel.

```
def count_folder_lines(self, path):
    """ 
        Use a buffer to count the number of line of each file among path.
        :param path: string pattern of a file type
        :return: number of lines in matching files
    """
    files = glob.glob(path, recursive=True)
    number = 0
    for file in files:
        f = open(file, 'rb')
        bufgen = takewhile(lambda x: x,
                           (f.raw.read(1024 * 1024) for _ in repeat(None)))
        number += sum(buf.count(b'\n') for buf in bufgen if buf)
    return number

def count_number_of_files(self, path):
    """
        Count number of files for a string pattern
        :param path: files string pattern
        :return: number of files matching the pattern
    """
    files = glob.glob(path, recursive=True)
    return len(files)

def multiproc(self):
    """
        Multiprocessing to launch several processes to count number of
        lines of each string pattern in self.files
        :return: List of number of files per string pattern
                    (list of int).
    """
    pool = mp.Pool()
    asyncResult = pool.map_async(self.count_folder_lines, self.files)
    return asyncResult.get()
```

**With this solution, it takes ~1.2s to count versus ~5s before.**

Have a good day!